# Rename texts in admin single order woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I always look for questions to see if someone has had it, but I can't find an answer after a long time.

I  renamed some wooocommerce chekout fields with the function:

```
function custom_rename_wc_checkout_fields ($ fields) {
```

For example I have renamed the placeholder and label "billing_last _name" as NIF/CIF with the function:

```
function custom_rename_wc_checkout_fields ($ fields) {
$ fields ['billing'] ['billing_last_name'] ['placeholder'] = 'NIF/CIF';
$ fields ['billing'] ['billing_last_name'] ['label'] = 'NIF/CIF';
return $ fields;
}
```

But I need to change the text also in admin single order so that when you have to create a new order from admin, the admintrator (or other role) knows the title of each field.

In the checkout page in "Billing first name" field, the customer will see NIF / CIF but when the administrator sees the field from the admin single order or he want create an order it will still appear as "Firt Name"

Does anyone know how I can change the texts?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this text with the filter `woocommerce_admin_billing_fields`
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data.html#40-90